# Ember Data multiple polymorphic relationships on the same model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to get multiple polymorphic relationships going on the same model. Previously I had just one, and that worked just fine. I extended the polymorphic class and it works.

See example: http://jsbin.com/yoduju/1

I have double extended my classes to get the second polymorphic relationship to work.

See example: http://jsbin.com/yoduju/7 But I am not comfortable with that. As it doesn't represent what is happening with the data accurately. Yes they are related in a way, but by no means do they depend on each other like that.

Doing some research some have suggested doing mixins. http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ds-model-polymorphism-and-multiple-polymorphic-associations/2317/18 And it has apparently been pulled into Ember Data https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1845 But I just can't get it to work.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to do this with my jsbin?

Thanks!